# How can I convince pylint that my list is iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint

I've got a Python application and because of a third-party library I have to use Python 2.7, but I'm trying to make the best of it.

I've downloaded PyLint 1.9.5 and I'm basically getting it to work.  One thing I'm stumbling over and can't find a solution to.

I've got some classes basically like this:

```
class Narg(object):
   [snip]

class Foo(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.bar = None   # type: Optional[list[Narg]]

   def find(self):
      if self.bar:
         for narg in self.bar:
            [snip]
```

pylint doesn't like this, it gives me

```
E:201,80: Non-iterable value self.bar is used in an iterating context (not-an-iterable)
```

The code runs fine, so it's actually good, how can I convince pylint of this?

Comment: how do you initialize `bar` at something else than `None` ?

Comment: There's a lot more to the Foo class than I have included there.  bar gets set to a list of Narg when they are received over a network connection.

Answer (score 5):

`pylint` has no way of knowing that `self.bar` might later be updated from being `None` to being an iterable. You therefore have 2 choices:

1. Instantiate `self.bar` as an empty iterable - e.g. `self.bar = []`
2. disable pylint: `self.bar = None  # pylint: disable=not-an-iterable`

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of Optional[], to tell pylint that this member is sometimes set and sometimes not, and when it is set, it's a list[Narg]?

Comment: I'm pretty sure mypy is smarter than this.  I use the exact same type of code all the time.  Maybe try (1) moving `self.bar` to a local variable first. or (2) changing the code to be `for narg in self.bar or ():`.  But yeah, I agree, this seems broken.

Comment: `mypy` != `pylint` - if you are using the former with typing, you probably don't need the latter (or at least have to put wup with these issues).